# Find out if JList has an item currently selected

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a JList which is populated after importing a file.
Is it possible to have the first item/element of the JList highlighted/selected.
I have browsed many places hoping to find a line along the lines of

```
list.setFocus(0);
//or
listSelectionEvent.setSelection(0);
//0 referring to index point of the list
```

Maybe this isn't even possible...
?

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to match with the question content. Is the title wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
    list.setSelectedIndex(0);
```